# Visual Studio 2015 Simulator not starting up

Tags: visual-studio, simulator

I am trying to build an UWP application for my school project, however when I try to run my project on the Simulator, it takes forever to load. Visual studio kept showing the "Starting the Simulator" window and the Simulator is stuck at the loading page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR2VY.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYJxc.jpg)

I have tried running the project on local machine and it works.
I have also tried to repair my visual studio but it didnt help.

Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have at least 8GB of RAM? I strongly recommended that + an SSD hard drive, otherwise it might never start up. Also check that Hyper-V is enabled and working (Start > Add or Remove Windows Features)